# RxJava remove duplicates from items based on criteria

Tags: android, filter, group-by, rx-java, distinct

In my project I retrieve a list of Operations from a XML report and upload the new operations to Firebase.
This is working fine:

```
//Go through de XML report emitting one node each time
Observable.merge(
    Observable.fromIterable(XML.convertToIterable(xmlReport.getElementsByTagName(IBConstants.CashTransactionNode))),
    Observable.fromIterable(XML.convertToIterable(xmlReport.getElementsByTagName(IBConstants.TradeNode))))
        .flatMap((Function<Node, ObservableSource<iIB>>) node ->

//For each XML node, convert it to the appropriate object (cashTransaction or Trade)
//I'm not interested on CashTransactions of type 'Other_fees' with description containing 'CONSOLIDATED SNAPSHOTS'
Observable.just(XML.getObjectFromXMLNode(node)))
    .filter(iIBTransaction -> !iIBTransaction.getDescription().contains(CashTransaction.OtherFees_filter))
    .flatMap((Function<iIB, ObservableSource<iIB>>) iIBTransaction ->

//Check if the new object already exists in Firebase (check transactionID)
//checkIfNewOperation returns new CashTransaction with all values to null if already exists so only new operations pass filter iIBTransaction.getTransactionID() != null
FirebaseClass.getInstance().checkIfNewOperation(iIBTransaction))
        .filter(iIBTransaction -> iIBTransaction.getTransactionID() != null)

//Create a list with all elements passing filter and return it
        .toList()
        .flatMap((Function<List<iIB>, SingleSource<List<iIB>>>) Single::just));
```

At this point I have the new operations as desired. The problem is that I don't generate the XML and I've noticed that some operations are duplicated. **I'd like to remove this operations but I'd like to determine if two operations are equal or not based on my criteria. In case they are equal, i'd combine all this equal operations into a single one and let the flow continue.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does this help ? http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/distinct.html

Comment: Sure. I've seen this operator but I'm not sure about how to apply my custom criteria to determine if two operations can be grouped together. Do you have any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distinct works on `Object.equals` and `Object.hashCode` comparison so if your items can be compared to each other directly, use the basic `distinct()` operator.

If they can't be compared or the `Object.equals` is not correct for this type of check, you have to project each item into an object that implements the proper `equals` and `hashCode`, then use `distinct(Function)`.

```java
// this is the non-equatable object you want to have distinct over
class MyObject {
   String value;
}

// this object provides proper equality checks
final class MyDistinctObject {

    final String value;

    MyDistinctObject(MyObject obj) {
        this.value = obj.value;
    }

    @Override public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other instanceof MyDistincObject) {
            return value.equals(((MyDistinctObject)other).value);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() {
        return value.hashCode();
    }
}

// find the distinct elements of MyObjects based on the equality checks of the helper
sourceOfMyObjects.distinct(MyDistinctObject::new)
```